# Responsive Menu with Dropdown Elements

Tags: yui-pure-css, pure-css

Mostly I'm copying the [demo code](https://purecss.io/layouts/tucked-menu-vertical/) from the PureCSS "docs" for implementing their [dropdown menu](https://github.com/yahoo/pure/blob/master/src/menus/css/menus-dropdown.css).

I have created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/MikeiLL/pen/MvZyVO), and will share code here as well.

The problem is that in the vertical version, the submenu items are not being revealed on hover or on click.

I am presuming this is by design and am not sure if it is expected that additional JavaScript ([example](https://purecss.io/js/menus.js)) should be composed to enable reveal on click for touch devices and the like.

What I have is:

HTML:

```
<h1>PureCSS.io Responsive Nav Test</h1>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/grids-responsive-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-nn4HPE8lTHyVtfCBi5yW9d20FjT8BJwUXyWZT9InLYax14RDjBj46LmSztkmNP9w" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a href="#" class="custom-toggle" id="toggle"><s class="bar"></s><s class="bar"></s><s class="bar"></s></a>
 <nav class="custom-wrapper pure-menu custom-restricted-width pure-u-1" id="menu">
    <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal custom-can-transform">
      <ul id="menu-header-nav-menu" class="pure-menu-list">
        <li class="pure-menu-item">
           <a class="pure-menu-link" class='pure-menu-link' href="#">One</a>
        </li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item">
           <a class="pure-menu-link" class='pure-menu-link' href="#">Two</a>
         </li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item">
          <a class="pure-menu-link" class='pure-menu-link' href="#">Three</a>
        </li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-has-children pure-menu-allow-hover">
          <a class="pure-menu-link" class='pure-menu-link' href="#">Parent</a>
          <ul class="pure-menu-children">
              <li class="pure-menu-item">
              <a class="pure-menu-link" class='pure-menu-link' href="#">Child One</a>
             </li>
               <li class="pure-menu-item">
               <a class="pure-menu-link" class='pure-menu-link' href="#">Child Two</a>
             </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </nav>
```

CSS:

```
  .site-header {
      position: relative;
  }

  .custom-wrapper {
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      height: 2.1em;
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
      -moz-transition: height 0.5s;
      -ms-transition: height 0.5s;
      transition: height 0.5s;
  }

  .custom-wrapper.open {
      height: 14em;
  }

  .custom-wrapper {
      height: 0;
  }

  .custom-toggle {
      width: 34px;
      height: 34px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      display: none;
  }

  .custom-toggle {
      display: block;
  }

  .custom-toggle .bar {
      background-color: #777;
      display: block;
      width: 20px;
      height: 2px;
      border-radius: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 18px;
      right: 7px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
      transition: all 0.5s;
  }

  .custom-toggle .bar:first-child {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
      -moz-transform: translateY(-6px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
      transform: translateY(-6px);
  }

  .custom-toggle .bar:last-child {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(+6px);
      -moz-transform: translateY(+6px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(+6px);
      transform: translateY(+6px);
  }

  .custom-toggle.x .bar:last-child {
      display: none;
  }

  .custom-toggle.x .bar {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  .custom-toggle.x .bar:first-child {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }

  @media (min-width: 47.999em) {
    .custom-toggle {
        display: none;
    }

    .custom-wrapper {
      height: 3.2em;
      overflow: visible;
    }

    .pure-menu-children .pure-menu-item {
      background-color: #999;
    }
  }
```

Javascript:

```
(function (window, document) {
  var menu = document.getElementById('menu'),
      WINDOW_CHANGE_EVENT = ('onorientationchange' in window) ? 'orientationchange':'resize';

  function toggleHorizontal() {
      [].forEach.call(
          document.getElementById('menu').querySelectorAll('.custom-can-transform'),
          function(el){
              el.classList.toggle('pure-menu-horizontal');
          }
      );
  };

  function toggleMenu() {
      // set timeout so that the panel has a chance to roll up
      // before the menu switches states
      if (menu.classList.contains('open')) {
          setTimeout(toggleHorizontal, 500);
      }
      else {
          toggleHorizontal();
      }
      menu.classList.toggle('open');
      document.getElementById('toggle').classList.toggle('x');
  };

  function closeMenu() {
      if (menu.classList.contains('open')) {
          toggleMenu();
      }
  }

  document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      toggleMenu();
      e.preventDefault();
  });

  window.addEventListener(WINDOW_CHANGE_EVENT, closeMenu);
})(this, this.document);
```

Am I correctly presuming that I need to handle the mobile subnav with additional script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was happening is that the "children" were off-page.

I'm not sure why it was required to modify the basic yui-pure-css mark-up, but to make this work in this case, I modified the following two items for the small screen sizes:

```
.pure-menu-has-children {
  position: relative;
}

.pure-menu-children {
    left: 3em;
    top: 2em;
}
```

The `.pure-menu-children` `ul` has `position: absolute`, but I'm not sure what it's `relative` parent is. Maybe it's the `ul`. At any rate, making it's relative parent the `.pure-menu-has-children` `li` facilitates it being displayed in relation to the parent list item.

I'm using a mobile first approach, so then for the media query for the larger viewports it can be restored to the framework defaults:

```
.pure-menu-children {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

However I think I prefer it as it is on the smaller devices. Here's an updated [Pen](https://codepen.io/MikeiLL/pen/prqWZr).

Not completely happy. Maybe the vertical menu doesn't need to be quite so wide. I'm also, in this case, finding the need to add to `.pure-menu-link` a `text-align: left`, because the `child item` still seems to be aligning based on a full-width item.